# Single case multiple record types crud access single profile

Tags: apex, profile, administration

we have 3 record types on case object.
Case, QAR and CAPA

For an profile named Quality
we need to provide

Case record type Read access only.
QAR record type Create, Read and Edit
CAPA record type create, read and Edit.

what is the best approach to do this, is it possible with standard permission set and profiles setup. As there we can provide access base on object level not record type.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Record Type from their profile won't actually prevent editing those records, simply the ability to change a record's Record Type to that type. You have two basic options here: [Criteria-Based Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rules_criteria.htm&type=5) or [Validation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_defining_field_validation_rules.htm&type=5).

Using the first option, you can share records that meet certain criteria with a Role or Public Group. You could write a Flow or Trigger to ensure that users in a given profile are in a Public Group if that makes things easier.

With Validation Rules, you can prevent users from successfully saving a record they shouldn't be able to edit, but they'll still see the Edit button and be able to get to the Edit page, so this approach isn't the best user experience.